# Onsubmit and history push is not working react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using material ui but then when i click on submit it doesn't redirect.I'm using withRouter but then what happens is ex.,

```
   http://localhost:3000/SignIn
```

it redirects to

```
  http://localhost:3000/SignIn?email=abc%40yahoo.in&password=dddddddddddddd
```

I've **src/components/userDashboard** where when click onto sign in it must redirect.As nothing but a redirect if successful to check whether routes work or not.

1)**One thing i dont understand here is if user dont have any history n have come first time then will this history work?** or I'm doing something wrong?I'm new to this routing I dont have any idea as to what I'm supposed to do?

```
     this.props.history.push('/Userdashboard');
```

src/SingIn.js

```
                import React from 'react';
            import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
            import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
            import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
            import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
            import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
            import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
            import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
            import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
            import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
            import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
            import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
            import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
            import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
            import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

            const styles = theme => ({
            main: {
                width: 'auto',
                display: 'block', // Fix IE 11 issue.
                marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
                marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
                [theme.breakpoints.up(400 + theme.spacing.unit * 3 * 2)]: {
                width: 400,
                marginLeft: 'auto',
                marginRight: 'auto',
                },
            },
            paper: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 8,
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center',
                padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 2}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px`,
            },
            avatar: {
                margin: theme.spacing.unit,
                backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
            },
            form: {
                width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
                marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
            },
            submit: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
            },
            });

            class SignIn extends React.Component {

                handleSubmit(){
                      //as nothing but a redirect if successfull to check whether routes work or not
                    this.props.history.push('/Userdashboard');
                }

                render(){
                    const { classes } =this.props;
                // handleSubmit();
                    return (
                        <main className={classes.main}>
                        <CssBaseline />
                        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                            <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                            <LockIcon />
                            </Avatar>
                            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                            Sign in
                            </Typography>
                            <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                                <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
                                <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" autoFocus />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                                <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                                <Input name="password" type="password" id="password" autoComplete="current-password" />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                                label="Remember me"
                            />
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                className={classes.submit}
                            >
                                Sign in
                            </Button>
                            </form>
                        </Paper>
                        </main>
                    );
                }
            }

            SignIn.propTypes = {
            classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            };

            export default  withRouter(withStyles(styles)(SignIn));
```

2)**Why is the on submit not routing to the route?** It's pretty difficult to understand?

I get the following error

```
                TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
                handleSubmit
                E:/reacr-redux/src/components/SignIn.js:53
                50 | 
                51 | handleSubmit(event){
                52 |     event.preventDefault();
                > 53 |      this.props.history.push('/Userdashboard');
                    | ^  54 | }
                55 | 
                56 | render(){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using babel's plugin stage-1, you should use this format for that function

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.history.push('/Userdashboard');
}
```

else, you may want to use constructor binding, at the top of your class, such like:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

[read this article for details.](https://codeburst.io/binding-functions-in-react-b168d2d006cb)

Comment: i did it onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} my bad had forgotten.Can u please lemme know where do i find this  "babel's plugin stage-1" in my project i dont find it in package.json

Comment: this will be a full ref, https://medium.com/@joshblack/writing-a-react-component-in-es2015-a0b27e1ed50a

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.props.history.push('/Userdashboard');
            }
```

This history.push will work for first time.

Comment: dosen't work. throws error.I 've updated I've update my question. TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined